# Cosmic function points to lines of code

Tags: embedded, metrics, function-points

I would like to know if there is a way to convert [COSMIC function points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COSMIC_Software_Sizing) to lines of code (as you can do with classic [function point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point)).

I need to have a measure of how many lines an embedded software developed in C is going to have, I don't have any other metrics available but the measure of the software in cosmic function points.

P.S. if you know a different/better approach to estimate LOC for embedded software I would like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

How about analogy based estimation? (taking a similar project or relevant parts of several projects) we use Weighted Micro Function Points extensively for that with pretty decent results:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Micro_Function_Points

:)

Answer (score 0):

How about automating your functional size measurement/estimation using [ScopeMaster](https://www.Scopemaster.com).  This will give you an estimated Function Point size, LOC, development costs, schedule, defect potentials and much, much more.